# Change height to 0px of element with padding

Tags: html, css

Consider the example below. I have an element which *margin is orange*, *border is black*, *padding is blue* and *content box is red*.

**Reproduce**

1. Toggle the *box-sizing* of *.box* between *content-box* and *border-box*. Notice that the padding and border is included in the height. Keep it to *border-box*.
2. Now start decrease the *height* property of *.box*. First to *52px* and then further down to *0px*

**Questions**

1. The height of the *.box* is not affected between *52px* and *0px*. Why is this? Is there a way to decrease the height further down?
2. Let's say the *.box* contains data that are receieved in real-time trough websocket. I want to animate the data coming into the screen by using css3. The box should increase its height from 0 to full height similar to jquery [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/). I set *transition all 0.3s*. What is the initial css and the post-data css? `style="padding:0;height:0;"` to `style="padding:16px;height:auto"`? Is there a hardware-accelerated way to to the animation?

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C33838, #C33838), linear-gradient(to bottom, #0012FF, #0012FF), linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000, #000000);
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box, border-box;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #926C0C;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 16px;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin: 30px;">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of what "border-box" is:**

> *border-box:* The width and height properties (and min/max properties)
>   includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

Normally, if NOT specifically set to `border-box`, the height and width would only refer to the content.  Padding and border are added on top of that.

---

**Your example:**

So when you set your height to 52px, the content is gone and all that remains (not including the margin) is the 52px worth of padding and borders.

```
padding total = 32px
border total  = 20px
total         = 52px
```

---

**Reason you can't lower it more:**

Per [developer.mozilla.org's 'box-sizing' page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), you cannot make the height of the content negative, which in your case is anything lower than 52px.

> The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it
>   impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.